# Bajar el peso de una imagen de subida php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagen

Muy buenas noches comunidad, tengo el siguiente problema, tengo el código corriendo perfectamente para subir las imagenes, también tengo un script que no deje subir imagenes mayores a 3MB. El problema es que la mayoria de celulares si toma la foto directamente desde la camara les toma la foto a 4mb o hasta más, el cual ocasionaría un error. Mi jefe quiere que deje de salir la alerta y que el programa automaticamente le baje la calidad o el tamaño de la imagen al subirla al servidor.

```
public function Subircuenta($id)
{
    $mi_archivo = 'img';
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/certificadosBanco/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|png|jpeg";
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($mi_archivo)) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo json_encode($error);
    } else {
        $data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());
        $imagen = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $arre = array(
            "img" => $imagen,

        );
        $this->Model_login->subirCuenta($arre );
        redirect(base_url() . "Perfil/perfil2", "refresh");
    }
}
```

no hay necesidad de explicar lo del if, toda la funcionalidad de subir archivos lo hace antes del if.

Este es el input que recibe

```
    <input type="file" class="form-control" aria-label="img" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="miInput" name="img">


const MAXIMO_TAMANIO_BYTES = 3000000; // 1MB = 1 millón de bytes
    // Obtener referencia al elemento
    const $miInput = document.querySelector("#miInput");
    $miInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
      // si no hay archivos, regresamos
      if (this.files.length <= 0) return;
      // Validamos el primer archivo únicamente
      const archivo = this.files[0];
      if (archivo.size > MAXIMO_TAMANIO_BYTES) {
        const tamanioEnMb = MAXIMO_TAMANIO_BYTES / 1000000;
        alert(`El tamaño máximo es ${tamanioEnMb} MB`);
        // Limpiar
        $miInput.value = "";
      } else {
        // Validación pasada. Envía el formulario o haz lo que tengas que hacer
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los muchos que han tenido este inconveniente así lo solucioné, Por si quieren realizar las pruebas necesarias

Vista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        ::selection {
            background-color: #E13300;
            color: white;
        }

        ::-moz-selection {
            background-color: #E13300;
            color: white;
        }


        .error {
            color: #E13300;
        }

        .success {
            color: darkgreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <center>
            <h1>Ecomm</h1>

            <p>Escoge cédula frontal</p>
            <?php
            if (isset($success) && strlen($success)) {
                echo '<div class="success">';
                echo '<p>' . $success . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            if (isset($errors) && strlen($errors)) {
                echo '<div class="error">';
                echo '<p>' . $errors . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            if (validation_errors()) {
                echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>');
            }
            if (isset($resize_img)) {
                redirect(base_url("Probar/updateCuenta"));
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            $attributes = array('name' => 'image_upload_form', 'id' => 'image_upload_form');
            echo form_open_multipart($this->uri->uri_string(), $attributes);
            ?>
            <p><input name="image_name" class="form-control" id="image_name" readonly="readonly" type="file" /></p>
            <p><input name="image_resize" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" type="submit" /></p>
            <?php
            echo form_close();
            ?>
        </center>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

controlador que hace la funcion de subir la imagen, ya al guardalo a la base de datos queda decisión de ustedes:

```
//variable for storing error message
private $error;
//variable for storing success message
private $success;

//appends all error messages
private function handle_error($err)
{
    $this->error .= nl2br($err . "\n");
}

//appends all success messages
private function handle_success($succ)
{
    $this->success .= nl2br($succ . "\n");
}

public function updateCuenta()
{
    if ($this->input->post('image_resize')) {
        //set preferences
        //file upload destination
        $upload_path = './asset/images/confirmacion/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
        //allowed file types. * means all types
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg|web';
        //allowed max file size. 0 means unlimited file size
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        //max file name size
        $config['max_filename'] = '255';

        //store image info once uploaded
        $image_data = array();
        //check for errors
        $is_file_error = FALSE;
        //check if file was selected for upload
        if (!$_FILES) {
            $is_file_error = TRUE;
            $this->handle_error('Selecciona una imagen');
        }

        //if file was selected then proceed to upload
        if (!$is_file_error) {
            //load the preferences
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            //check file successfully uploaded. 'image_name' is the name of the input
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_name')) {
                //if file upload failed then catch the errors
                $this->handle_error($this->upload->display_errors());
                $is_file_error = TRUE;
            } else {
                //store the file info
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path']; //get original image
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 900;
                $config['height'] = 850;
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $file = $image_data['file_name'];
               
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    $this->handle_error($this->image_lib->display_errors());
                }
            }
        }
        // There were errors, we have to delete the uploaded image
        if ($is_file_error) {
            if ($image_data) {
                $file = $upload_path . $image_data['file_name'];
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $data['resize_img'] = $upload_path . $image_data['file_name'];
            $this->handle_success('Image was successfully uploaded to direcoty <strong>' . $upload_path . '</strong> and resized.');
        }
    }

    //load the error and success messages
    $data['perfil'] = $this->Model_login->cargar_datos_comercio();

    $data['errors'] = $this->error;
    $data['success'] = $this->success;
    //load the view along with data
    $this->load->view('resize', $data);
}
```